# Django inner join on

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

First of all, I want to say that i've checked all the similar questions and none of them was the answer to my question.

I have `Friend` and `User` models.

**Friend Model**

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False, related_name='%(class)s_requests_created')
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False, null=True, blank=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**User Model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=191, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Lets think of 3 users. User A, B, C. `B` is following `A` and `C` is following `B`. **(I'm `C`)** What i want to achieve is Get user `A` based on user `B` that is following user `A`.

Pretty simple query but a little bit complicated with Django QuerySet.

**This is my query**

```
SELECT U2.username FROM `accounts_friend`

INNER JOIN `accounts_user` U1 ON accounts_friend.following_id = U1.id AND U1.is_active = 1
INNER JOIN `accounts_friend` F1 ON accounts_friend.following_id = F1.user_id AND F1.accepted = 1 AND F1.deleted_at IS NULL AND F1.user_id != F1.following_id
INNER JOIN `accounts_user` U2 ON F1.following_id = U2.id AND U2.is_active = 1

WHERE accounts_friend.accepted = 1 AND accounts_friend.deleted_at IS NULL AND accounts_friend.user_id != accounts_friend.following_id
```

**Here's what i've done but definitely not even close**.

```
users = Friend.objects.filter(
    Q(user=request.user) & Q(accepted=True) & Q(deleted_at__isnull=True) & Q(following__is_active=True) & ~Q(following=request.user)
).annotate(
    username=F('following__friend__following__username')
).values('username')
```

If something is not clear, please let me know to add more details.

Comment: You want to get all users that are following another user? Have you considered using a `ManyToManyField` using your `Friend` model as the through table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for such `User` objects:

```
User.objects.filter(
    ~Q(friend__user_id=F('pk')),
    ~Q(friend__user__friend__user_id=F('friend__user_id')),
    is_active=True,
    friend__accepted=True,
    friend__deleted_at=None,
    friend__user__is_active=True,
    friend__user__friend__accepted=True,
    friend__user__friend__deleted_at=None,
    friend__user__friend__user=request.user
)
```

It is normally better to query for *model objects*, than for database values. Since model objects are "richer": they have defined behavior, and can easily be passed to perform processing.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should give you all `Users` that are being followed by a `user`

```
User.objects.filter(
    is_active=True,
    friend__user=request.user,
    friend__accepted=True,
    friend__deleted_at__isnull=True
)
```